# Use or in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use `||` in this example:

```
(from p in DbContext.Posts where p.Name == str || where p.Category == str
select new PostResponse(){
      //some properties here
})
```

but it gives me an error. Any way how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the second `where`.

```cs
from p in DbContext.Posts where p.Name == str || p.Category == str
```